# Visual Studio Release management from bit buclket

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, azure-devops

I have a question about setting up CI/CD for my WebAPI project. I am using Bitbucket as my code repository and I was planning to use visual studio release management to for CI. I was wondering if its possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you need to use the "Build" feature in Visual Studio Team Service for CI since Release Management is for CD.

For the configuration, refer to this link for details: [Visual Studio Team Services: Connecting a BitBucket Repository](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34313.visual-studio-team-services-connecting-a-bitbucket-repository.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Eddie. I could connect and build with VS build. Just going further from there, I wanted to setup CD to Azure WebApp. Sorry but this is my first CI/CD task

Comment: @Jay What do you use to run the build? Visual Studio or Visual Studio Team Service?

Comment: Visual Studio Team Service... I exactly followed the instructions provided in the article suggested by you and I could build my project. When I added build definition, I got few tasks automatically added Get sources, NuGet restore ***.sln, Build solution ***.sln, Test Assemblies, Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory), Publish Artifact: drop) I believe I need to add another task for publishing artifact to Azure?

Comment: @Jay Yes, you can add an "Azure Web App Deployment" step in your definition to deploy your web app to azure. Refer to this link for details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnet4-to-azure

Comment: Thanks Eddie.. I'll give it a go

Comment: @Jay No problem. Let me know if you meet any other issues.

Comment: Hi Eddie, I got it working as per your instructions... Many thanks.  However I tried to change the process a bit and have separate definition for build and release now and I have another problem now... Here is my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998120/sql-connection-error-after-deploying-through-vs-team-service-release-management

Comment: @Jay Can you mark it as answer if it works. :) I will check your new issue and provide some solution if I know.