# SQL connection error after deploying through VS team service release management

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have setup build for my WebAPI project through VS team service Builds for continuous integration and I am using VS team service release management continuous deployment to Azure Web App. I am not getting any errors while build or release however when I try to access my Apis through swagger, I get "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server".

Here is what I have as a connection string in VSTS release definition
-connectionString @{"xxxx"="Server=tcp:xxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxxxdb;User ID=xxxxdbuser@xxxx;Password=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"}

This is my first attempt to setup CI/CD and I would appreciate any help.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you check if the data connection is correct from Azure portal?

Comment: Seems like it is correct. I also tried publishing through VS 2015 and I works fine.

Comment: Can you share the detailed error message?

Comment: Many thanks for your help Eddie. You have been the biggest help for my whole task of CI/CD. The solution was I had to create a connection string in my Web.config which is not named as defaultConnection and name it same as in my VSTS release definition.

Comment: No problem, you can mark your solution as answer after 24 hours. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a connection string in my Web.config which is not named as defaultConnection and name it same as in my VSTS release definition.